# php json decode weird format

Tags: php, json, embedded-linux

I'm trying to decode some data from my IP alarm system. I have been told that the data is json, and looking through the html files, there are references to json. The problem is that it looks a little wierd :-)

Here are the raw output from the alarm:

```
/*-secure- {    senrows : [ {no : "1", type : "Door Contact", zone : "1", name : "zone1", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "2", type : "Door Contact", zone : "2", name : "zone2", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "3", type : "Door Contact", zone : "3", name : "zone3", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "4", type : "Door Contact", zone : "4", name : "zone4", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "Low", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "5", type : "Door Contact", zone : "5", name : "zone5", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "6", type : "Door Contact", zone : "6", name : "zone6", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "7", type : "Door Contact", zone : "7", name : "zone7", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "8", type : "Door Contact", zone : "8", name : "zone8", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "9", type : "Door Contact", zone : "9", name : "zone9", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "10", type : "IR Sensor", zone : "10", name : "zone10", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "Low", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "11", type : "Remote Keypad", zone : "11", name : "zone11", attr : "",cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}] } */
```

how to decode this data?? :-)

json_decode() does not work :-/

Comment: It seems you'll need to process it beforehand to put in real JSON format.

Comment: json is not valid. quotes are missing from keys.

Comment: whoever told you this is JSON should be fired. tell him that this is **not** valid. JSON requires keys to be encapsulated in quotation marks, like `"senrows"`. i'm afraid there is no quick fix - you have to parse the string yourself and place quotes around every word that's not in a string already. but you should really complain to whoever made this and demand they fix their code.

Comment: is it possible to turn it into valid son by stripping the unwanted text at start and end, and add quotes to the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you still should first and foremost demand from whoever gave you this output that they fix their code and actually deliver JSON.

still, i had a few minutes and enjoyed the coding exercise to write a quick fix for your data.
it only works if your code allways starts with the same `-secure-`, otherwise you have to adapt it.

and it *will* fail or produce weird results if for some reason you have a field with encapsulated strings, like `a:"text\"moretext\"finaltext"`, or if the providers introduce any other mistake besides the ones shown in your example.

```
<?php
$data = /*your not-JSON-string*/;

function fix_botched_json($data) {
    //remove comment-section, we don't need it
    $data = substr($data, 10, strlen($data)-12);
    $seek = '/(\w+)/';
    $exploded = explode('"', $data);
    //explode so we only replace *outside* of strings

    $outside = true;
    foreach($exploded as &$item) {
        if($outside) {
            //the regex matches only word characters.
            $item = preg_replace($seek, '"\1"', $item);
        }
        //alternating between inside and outside of strings
        $outside = !$outside;
    }
    //piece it back together
    $imploded = implode('"', $exploded);

    return $imploded;
}


$final = json_decode(fix_botched_json($data), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

very hacky solution and not guranteed to work with other strings you may have. There are many ways in which you can handle this situation, best way might be to ask the creator of the alarm system to start producing valid JSON !

```
<?php

$string = '/*-secure- {    senrows : [ {no : "1", type : "Door Contact", zone : "1", name : "zone1", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "2", type : "Door Contact", zone : "2", name : "zone2", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "3", type : "Door Contact", zone : "3", name : "zone3", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "4", type : "Door Contact", zone : "4", name : "zone4", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "Low", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "5", type : "Door Contact", zone : "5", name : "zone5", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "6", type : "Door Contact", zone : "6", name : "zone6", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "7", type : "Door Contact", zone : "7", name : "zone7", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "8", type : "Door Contact", zone : "8", name : "zone8", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "9", type : "Door Contact", zone : "9", name : "zone9", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "10", type : "IR Sensor", zone : "10", name : "zone10", attr : "Burglar", cond : "", battery : "Low", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}, {no : "11", type : "Remote Keypad", zone : "11", name : "zone11", attr : "",cond : "", battery : "", tamp : "", bypass : "No"}] } */';

function fix_json($st){
    $regex = '/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\s)(?=:)/i';
    return preg_replace($regex, '"$1"', $st);
}

$step1 = strstr($string, '{');
$step2 = rtrim($step1, '*/');


$data = fix_json($step2);

var_dump(json_decode($data, true));
```

Comment: nice code, but it also has potential problems. for example with the input `'{field : "some :thing"}'`, the data gets broken. you should add a note for that

Comment: `/*-secure- {    senrows :` has to be filtered from the result :-) Looks like some nice example I can work with :-)